# how do i search in a jtable via jtextfield

Tags: java, swing, search, jtable

How would I search a value entered through a jtextfield?

here is the successful code for jtable:

```
private JTable table;
private DefaultTableModel tableModel;
private JPanel centerPanel;

public JPanel centerPanel() {

    centerPanel = new JPanel();
    centerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));

    String col[] = { "Roll Number", "Full Name", "Gender" };
    tableModel = new DefaultTableModel( col, 0 );

    table = new JTable( tableModel );
    table.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));

    for( Student student : students ) {
        Object[] obj = { student.getRollNumber(), student.getName(), student.getGender() };         
        tableModel.addRow(obj);
    }


    centerPanel.add(table);


    return centerPanel;

}
```

I am looking for how do I search from this `JTable` through a `JTextfield`.

> Student Model (Java Class)

```
public class Student {

private String rollNumber;
private String name;
private String gender;

public Student(String rollNumber, String name, String gender) {
    this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getRollNumber() {
    return rollNumber;
}

public void setRollNumber(String rollNumber) {
    this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student [rollNumber=" + rollNumber + ", name=" + name + ", gender=" + gender + "]";
}}
```

This is the Student model that I am using to insert data in the jtable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to search data in jtable using jtextfield?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158089/how-to-search-data-in-jtable-using-jtextfield)

Comment: I have seen that question already, but it didn't solve my problem because it is implemented somehow else. @Itamar Green

Comment: well that gives the main idea... If you were planning on getting an answer you can just copy-paste into your project, then sorry - I can't help. But if you want to learn how to do this, then you can try to understand why the other answer works.

Comment: `JTable` supports filtering, see [How to use tables, Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for more details, [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500713/overlay-swing-text-label-as-text-is-entered/29506154#29506154) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401463/asking-what-is-wrong-with-enterpressed-method/23401519#23401519)

Comment: @ItamarGreen Since `JTable` has a well defined and documented filtering API already, I wouldn't consider that a reasonable duplicate, in fact, I'd consider it a bad example - IMHO

Comment: @MagProgrammer I think you're getting my question very well. Thanks